# How to clear react state in modal after closing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I've got a product card with product details shown. On the bottom, there is an 'edit' `button`. When `clicked` it shows a modal with prefilled `input` fields, that can be edited then saved. Modal can also be closed without saving **(but with input fields edited)**.

> My problem is that when a user edits the fields, then closes modal
>   (without saving), then opens it again, fields are not set to initial
>   value but are shown changed.

I've tried a variable with the initial state then after closing filling the state with it, but it did not work. Tried to react refs too, no joy.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Modal from 'react-modal';

const customStyles = {
...
};

Modal.setAppElement('#root');

class AdminButtons extends Component {

    state = {
        modalIsOpen: false,
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { id, inStock, name, price, type } = this.props.product
        this.setState({ id, inStock, name, price, type })
    }

    openModal = () => {
        this.setState({ modalIsOpen: true });
    }

    afterOpenModal = () => {
        ...
    }

    closeModal = () => {
        this.setState({ modalIsOpen: false });
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        const target = event.target
        const input = target.value
        const name = target.name
        this.setState({ [name]: input })
    }

    render() {
        const { product, remove } = this.props
        const { modalIsOpen, name, inStock, price, type } = this.state
        return (
            <>
                <button onClick={this.openModal}>EDIT</button>
                <Modal
                    isOpen={modalIsOpen}
                    onAfterOpen={this.afterOpenModal}
                    style={customStyles}
                    contentLabel="Edit "
                >
                    <h2 ref={subtitle => this.subtitle = subtitle}>Hello</h2>
                    <button onClick={this.closeModal}>close</button>
                    <div>{this.props.product.name}</div>
                    <form>
                        <label>
                            Name
                            <input name="name" type="text" value={name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </label>
                        <label>inStock
                            <input name="inStock" type="text" value={inStock} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            Price
                            <input name="price" type="text" value={price} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            Type
                            <input name="type" type="text" value={type} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </label>
                        <button onClick={ () => {
                            this.props.edit(this.state)
                            this.closeModal() }
                            }>Save changes</button>
                    </form>
                </Modal>
                {product.isRemoved ?
                    <button> add </button> :
                    <button onClick={() => remove(product.id)}>remove</button>
                }
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: The original values should still be in the props. So when the modal is closed, just call `this.componentDidMount();` to reset the state.

Comment: what should happen when you press save should the values persist if you open again ? or it should reset every time you close it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the data from the inputs is in your component you can try something like this :
In `closeModal` you can set the initial state of the component

```
const initialState = { name: null, inStock: null, price: null, type:null }

closeModal = () => {
        this.setState({ 
         ...initialState,
         modalIsOpen: false 
        });
    }
```

But if the state of the inputs is coming from the Parent you need a new method to reset the data of the parent component that could be added as a callback in the same method.

```
const initialState = { name: null, inStock: null, price: null, type:null }

closeModal = () => {
        this.setState({ 
         modalIsOpen: false 
        }, () => {
        this.props.resetInputData();
      });
    }
```

Comment: Second suggestion worked. I combined your answer with @chris-g one. I created a a separate method  (clearInputFields) and placed componentDidMount inside it and it works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Your problem is that the modal isn't being unmounted, but only not displayed. This can be fixed using:

```
{modalIsOpen && <Modal
  isOpen={modalIsOpen}
  onAfterOpen={this.afterOpenModal}
  style={customStyles}
  contentLabel="Edit "
> modal content here! </Modal>
```

Comment: This works fine on Windows or Android, but it will cause the dialog not showing up on iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the sole creator of this solution but it feels relevant to this topic for anyone still getting this issue.

What I did was add a new hook variant named useTimeout which in itself is very easy to use and will reset the states for you.

1. Add a folder called "hooks" as a child to your src folder
2. Inside the "hooks" folder create a file called useTimeout.tsx
3. Copy paste the useTimeout code below.

```js
import React from 'react';

export function useTimeout(callback: () => void, delay: number | null | undefined) {
    const timeoutRef = React.useRef<number | undefined>();
    const callbackRef = React.useRef<any>(callback);
  
    // Remember the latest callback:
    //
    // Without this, if you change the callback, when setTimeout kicks in, it
    // will still call your old callback.
    //
    // If you add `callback` to useEffect's deps, it will work fine but the
    // timeout will be reset.
  
    React.useEffect(() => {
      callbackRef.current = callback;
    }, [callback]);
  
    // Set up the timeout:
  
    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (typeof delay === 'number') {
        timeoutRef.current = window.setTimeout(() => callbackRef.current(), delay);
  
        // Clear timeout if the components is unmounted or the delay changes:
        return () => window.clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
      }

      return () => null;
    }, [delay]);
  
    // In case you want to manually clear the timeout from the consuming component...:
    return timeoutRef;
  }
```

4. Inside your modal component, import the useTimeout hook like below:

   `import { useTimeout } from '../../../hooks/useTimeout';`
5. Use it above the return() of your component like below:

   `useTimeout(() => reset state), activate when true ? when true wait milliseconds before : null);`

   example:
   `useTimeout(() => setState({ ...state, currentStep: '' }), !props.open ? 350 : null);`