# Updating a key with setState to unmount the component its called in?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My goal is an alternative solution to [reset state after closing a modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207054/how-to-clear-react-state-in-modal-after-closing).

I have a `<Page>` and within it a `<Modal>`. I want the modal's cancel button to call the function `resetModal()`, which should unmount the modal by generating a new key. Currently my code looks something like this...

```
const Page = () => {
    const [myKey, setMyKey] = useState(generateKey());

    return (
        <div>a bunch of stuff here</div>
        <Modal key={myKey} resetModal={() => setMyKey(generateKey())} />
    )
}
```

But when I dismiss the modal and call `resetModal()`, it's throwing this error.

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
```

Why is it throwing the error? Is it because the node it's trying to remove is itself? I don't understand what's happening here.

Comment: you usually get this error when it has something to do with dom manipulation outside react. you're trying to remove/do something a component that is not managed by react. i can't say anything more without a [mre]